# WKWebView Screenshots

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to capture the image that the webview is displaying to the user, so I can some color analysis of the web page. When I try to get the image from it's parent, I am basically getting a white box, even though the page has rendered:

```
func makeImageSnapshot()-> (NSImage)
{


    let imgSize = self.view.bounds.size
    let bir = self.viewbitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect(self.webView!.view.bounds)

    bir.size = imgSize
    self.webView.cacheDisplayInRect(self.view.bounds, toBitmapImageRep:bir)

    let image = NSImage(size:imgSize)
    image.addRepresentation(bir)
    self.image = image

    return image
}

func saveSnapshot()
{
    let imgRep = self.image!.representations[0]
    let data = imgRep.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: nil)
    data.writeToFile("/tmp/file.png", atomically: false)

}
```

It looks to me like I can't get access to the properties of the actual view (in this case the bounds) inside of the webView. When I try to access it, the compiler barfs:

/Users/josh/Canary/MacOsCanary/canary/canary/Modules/Overview/Overview.swift:55:37: '(NSView!, stringForToolTip: NSToolTipTag, point: NSPoint, userData: UnsafePointer<()>) -> String!' does not have a member named 'bounds'

My guess is that this is happening due to the extensions approach used by OS X and iOS.  Any ideas, or should I just go back to using the legacy WebView?

Comment: You're trying to access "bounds" on a String!.

Comment: @Josh have you found a solution for iOS? Currently i'm using snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates. But I have to call it after the webview is rendered, so I wait for a 0.1 secs in didFinishNavigation and call snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates. Not very convinient and reliably(

Comment: Please refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50962265/3659227

Answer (score 2):

I realise the question was for Mac OS X, but I found this page whilst searching for an iOS solution. My answer below doesn't work on Mac OS X as the drawViewHierarchyInRect() API call is currently iOS only, but I put it here for reference for other iOS searchers.

This [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412791/2067021) solved it for me on iOS 8 with a WKWebView. That answer's sample code is in Objective-C but the Swift equivalent to go in a UIView sub-class or extension would be along the lines of the code below. The code ignores the return value of drawViewHierarchyInRect(), but you may want to pay attention to it.

```
func imageSnapshot() -> UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 0);
    self.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true);
    let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
extension WKWebView {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 0);
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true);
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return snapshotImage;
    }
}
```

*Note: This solution only works on iOS.*

Comment: This only capture the visible area, not fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in the same boat today but found a solution (by using private APIs).

If you're not targeting the App Store and generally are not afraid of using private APIs, here's a way to capture screenshots of WKWebView's on OS X:

https://github.com/lemonmojo/WKWebView-Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have access to a target writeable place - the snapshotURL ie.., such as the desktop, so we provide a handler for that:

```
func registerSnaphotsURL(_ sender: NSMenuItem, handler: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
    var targetURL : URL

    //  1st around authenticate and cache sandbox data if needed
    if isSandboxed, desktopData == nil {
        targetURL =
            UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value.count == 0
                ? getDesktopDirectory()
                : URL.init(fileURLWithPath: UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value, isDirectory: true)
        
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.message = "Authorize access to "
        openPanel.prompt = "Authorize"
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        openPanel.directoryURL = targetURL
        openPanel.begin() { (result) -> Void in
            if (result == .OK) {
                targetURL = openPanel.url!
                
                //  Since we do not have data, clear any bookmark
                
                if self.storeBookmark(url: targetURL, options: self.rwOptions) {
                    self.desktopData = self.bookmarks[targetURL]
                    UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value = targetURL.absoluteString
                    if !self.saveBookmarks() {
                        print("Yoink, unable to save snapshot bookmark")
                    }

                    self.desktopData = self.bookmarks[targetURL]
                    handler(targetURL)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        targetURL =
            UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value.count == 0
                ? getDesktopDirectory()
                : URL.init(fileURLWithPath: UserSettings.SnapshotsURL.value, isDirectory: true)
        handler(targetURL)
    }
}
```

we wanted to allow single (view controller) and all current views (app delegate) so two actions in their respective files, both making use of the register handler.

**App Delegate**

```
@objc @IBAction func snapshotAllPress(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    registerSnaphotsURL(sender) { (snapshotURL) in
        //  If we have a return object just call them, else notify all
        if let wvc : WebViewController = sender.representedObject as? WebViewController {
            sender.representedObject = snapshotURL
            wvc.snapshot(sender)
        }
        else
        {
            sender.representedObject = snapshotURL
            let notif = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "SnapshotAll"), object: sender)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(notif)
        }
    }
}
```

**View Controller**

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(WebViewController.snapshotAll(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "SnapshotAll"),
        object: nil)
}

@objc func snapshotAll(_ note: Notification) {
    snapshot(note.object as! NSMenuItem)
}
```

view singleton action

```
@objc @IBAction func snapshotPress(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    guard let url = webView.url, url != webView.homeURL else { return }
    guard let snapshotURL = sender.representedObject as? URL else {
        //  Dispatch to app delegate to handle a singleton
        sender.representedObject = self
        appDelegate.snapshotAllPress(sender)
        return
    }
    
    sender.representedObject = snapshotURL
    snapshot(sender)
}
```

the webView interaction to capture an image

```
@objc func snapshot(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    guard let url = webView.url, url != webView.homeURL else { return }
    guard var snapshotURL = sender.representedObject as? URL else { return }
    
    //  URL has only destination, so add name and extension
    let filename = String(format: "%@ Shapshot at %@",
                          (url.lastPathComponent as NSString).deletingPathExtension,
                          String.prettyStamp())
    snapshotURL.appendPathComponent(filename)
    snapshotURL = snapshotURL.appendingPathExtension("png")
    
    webView.takeSnapshot(with: nil) { image, error in
        if let image = image {
            self.webImageView.image = image
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.processSnapshotImage(image, to: snapshotURL)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.userAlertMessage("Failed taking snapshot", info: error?.localizedDescription)
            self.webImageView.image = nil
        }
    }
}
```

and the capture to the targeted area

```
func processSnapshotImage(_ image: NSImage, to snapshotURL: URL) {
    guard let tiffData = image.tiffRepresentation else { NSSound(named: "Sosumi")?.play(); return }
    let bitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData)

    do
    {
        try bitmapImageRep?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])?.write(to: snapshotURL)
        // https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1913/_index.html
        if let asset = NSDataAsset(name:"Grab") {

            do {
                // Use NSDataAsset's data property to access the audio file stored in Sound.
                let player = try AVAudioPlayer(data:asset.data, fileTypeHint:"caf")
                // Play the above sound file.
                player.play()
            } catch {
                print("no sound for you")
            }
        }
        if snapshotURL.hideFileExtensionInPath(), let name = snapshotURL.lastPathComponent.removingPercentEncoding {
            print("snapshot => \(name)")
        }
    } catch let error {
        appDelegate.userAlertMessage("Snapshot failed", info: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```