# How can I take a snapshot of a UIView that isn't rendered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiimage

I use this method for taking a snapshot:

```
UIView *snapshotView = [someView snapshotAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

This gives me a UIView that I can play with.

But, I need the UIImage of it and not the UIView.

This is the method I use for converting a UIView to an UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)snapshotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImage *snapshot;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return snapshot;
}
```

It doesn't work, the snapshot is a blank UIImage because the snapshotView isn't rendered.

The obvious thing to do is to directly take a snapshot of the view instead of taking the snapshot in the form of a UIView and then converting it.

**The problem with the obvious method is that I'm using a WKWebView that has a huge bug that doesn't allow you to take screenshots. And that's true, I even reported the bug and they said they are trying to fix it.**

So, how can I take the snapshot (UIImage) of the snapshotView without rendering it?

Comment: @HussainShabbir - not a dupe, different question, different answer. The other answer might have done the job, but this one is the correct fit with apple's current apis. I understand it is substantially more efficient (although I haven't tested that claim)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`drawViewHierarchyInRect` will work for you. You can use this directly on your WKWebView.

There is some useful detail on [this Apple Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html). Also I touch on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198528/1375695) in answer to a slightly different question.

I use it in a category on UIView:

```
@implementation UIView (ImageSnapshot)
- (UIImage*)imageSnapshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, 
                                    YES, self.contentScaleFactor);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
@end
```

I don't know what you mean by 'the obvious method' - but I have tested this on a WKWebView and it works.

Comment: Hello @foundry, I'm curious if you still find this a valid solution with iOS 9.2 & Xcode 7.2 (7C68)?   I'm getting a white image.

Comment: @chinjazz: i've just tried Xcode 7.2 (7C68) with simulator versions of ios9.2 and ios8.4 (for comparison).. both work fine

Comment: Thanks for confirming!  I'm finding that in Simulator the screen image will render for the WKWebView the first time but not on next loads (where its a white image).. Could be a bug on my end, but I'll check it on a device for consistency.

Comment: I'm finding that with WKWebView adding a delay after webView sucCubus Navigation it works better...

Comment: drawViewHierarchyInRect distorts my image every single time i used it in my project, didn't anyone notice that it distorts and stretches your image?

Answer (score 9):

Since accepter answer didn't worked for me (`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returned `nil` all the time) I found [different solution](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-render-a-uiview-to-a-uiimage) for iOS10+:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
let image = renderer.image { _ in view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) }
```

P.S. You may want to call `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` before rendering