# Taking screenshot of a view with multiple subviews as wkwebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview

I have a View in iOS app where multiple wkwebview are added as subviews to render html contents. It shows all the content but when I try to take screen shot, it shows blank as if content is never rendered in  wkwebviews.

code I used to take screenshot:

```
 //view is parent view which contains wkwebviews as childviews
 func takeScreenShot(view: UIView) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image

}
```

When I check the UI Hierarchy, the content of wkwebviews are actually out of bound of the parent view. Is there proper way to take screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage* uiImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412791/2082569)

Comment: I had tried these lines of code. It freezes up the UI.