# How does cacheDisplayInRect work internally?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, wkwebview

How does `[NSView cacheDisplayInRect:(NSRect)rect toBitmapImageRep:(NSBitmapImageRep *)bitmapImageRep]` work internally when writes the bitmap data to the bitmapImageRep?

E.g. does it traverse and access the `CALayer layer` of all the subviews and combine them when `...cacheDisplayInRect...` is called or does it simply write it's own layer (which then is already contains the representation data for all subviews).

**Background to my question:** I use a native control (WKWebView) that is broken when it comes to screenshots ([example SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727499/wkwebview-screenshots)), and instead of reinventing the wheel to take an screenshot of the whole app including the WKWebView I would like to fix the method that Cocoa uses for bitmap representations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some trial and error and figured out that both ...cacheDisplayInRect... and ...drawInContext... calls - [NSView drawRect:] internally to render the elements.

#### - [CALayer drawInContext:context] call stack

```
#0  0x000000010000e28c in -[DXSecureWKWebView drawRect:] at /Users/x/dev/X/XSecureWKWebView.m:34
#1  0x00007fff8d386749 in -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] ()
#2  0x00007fff8d386afe in -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] ()
#3  0x00007fff8d386afe in -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] ()
#4  0x00007fff8d386168 in __46-[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:]_block_invoke ()
#5  0x00007fff8d385e11 in -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] ()
#6  0x00007fff8d385493 in -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
```

#### - [NSView cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:] call stack

```
#0  0x000000010000e2dc in -[XSecureWKWebView drawRect:] at /Users/x/dev/x/XSecureWKWebView.m:34
#1  0x00007fff8d386749 in -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] ()
#2  0x00007fff8d65fe1c in __50-[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderForegroundInContext:]_block_invoke ()
#3  0x00007fff8d385e11 in -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] ()
#4  0x00007fff8d50b740 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderForegroundInContext:] ()
#5  0x00007fff934f5ce1 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#6  0x00007fff934f7aaf in -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#7  0x00007fff8d50b807 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#8  0x00007fff934f5cf0 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#9  0x00007fff934f7aaf in -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#10 0x00007fff8d50b807 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#11 0x00007fff934f5cf0 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#12 0x00007fff934f7aaf in -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#13 0x00007fff8d50b807 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#14 0x00007fff934f5cf0 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#15 0x00007fff934f7aaf in -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#16 0x00007fff8d50b807 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#17 0x00007fff934f5cf0 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#18 0x00007fff934f7aaf in -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#19 0x00007fff8d50b807 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#20 0x00007fff934f5cf0 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#21 0x00007fff934f7aaf in -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#22 0x00007fff8d50b807 in -[_NSViewBackingLayer _renderSublayersInContext:] ()
#23 0x00007fff934f5cf0 in -[CALayer renderInContext:] ()
#24 0x00007fff8d50b11d in -[NSView _layerBackedDisplayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:isRootView:flipContextIfNeedeed:] ()
#25 0x00007fff8d50ac74 in -[NSView displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:] ()
#26 0x00007fff8d65f685 in __62-[NSView cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:includeSubviews:]_block_invoke ()
#27 0x00007fff8d65f3dc in __36-[NSBitmapImageRep _captureDrawing:]_block_invoke ()
#28 0x00007fff8d65f14c in -[NSBitmapImageRep _captureDrawing:] ()
#29 0x00007fff8d65f079 in -[NSView cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:includeSubviews:] ()
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know, how slow or fast `cacheDisplay(in:to:)` is. I am using it to convert SwiftUI views (via NSView) into an NSImage to place it into the mouse cursor. But my app is super slow and I am having trouble finding out why. Would it make sense to use `NSView draw()` to manually transform NSView (converted from SwiftUI View) into an NSImage?

Comment: @j.unruh I am afraid that I have no idea, it was a few years ago last time that I dug into iOS library internals. Hope you have figured it out in some other way.

Comment: If someone else is reading this at some point and has a similar issue: Using Cocoa Drawing and NSViews instead of SwiftUI View did the trick for me. Converting SwiftUI Views via `cacheDisplay(in:to:)` to NSImage was super slow for me. Creating NSViews with Cocoa Drawing and converting them to NSImage via `dataWithPDF(inside:)` sped up the NSImage creation by a factor of ~10.